# Grails Many-to-Many Relationship with a domain which has String id column

Tags: grails, many-to-many, grails-orm

How to create many-to-many relationship with a domain whose id column is a string?

**UnitObj** value examples are: '0','1','001','002','1234' etc.
So I can't make the id column(value column in UnitObj) **long** or **integer** because of those values.

Any help would be appreciated.
Here are the domains:

```
class UnitObj {
    String value
    String unit
    UnitObj parent

    static constraints = {
        value(unique: true, nullable: false)
        unit(nullable: false)
        parent(nullable: true)
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
        id generator: 'assigned', name: "value", type: 'string'
        table name: "unit_obj", schema: "db"
    }
}
```

Here is the one which I want to change.

```
class UserUnitObj {
    User user
    String unit  //This should be UnitObj not string
    String subUnit //This should be UnitObj not string

    static constraints = {
       user(nullable: false)
       unit(nullable: false)
       subUnit(nullable: true)
    }
    static mapping = {
       version false
       table name: "user_unit_obj", schema: "db"
    }
}
```

---------**EDIT**--------

If I change the strings to UnitObj, when trying to create UserUnitObj it gives :

```
  UserUnitObj u = new UserUnitObj()
  u.user = User.get(userUnitJson.user)
  u.unit = UnitObj.findByValue(userUnitJson.unit.id.toString())
  u.subUnit = UnitObj.findByValue(userUnitJson.subUnit.id.toString())
  u.save(flush: true)
```

This is the error:

```
2016-12-05 17:51:14,305 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - ERROR: column "sub_unit_id" is of type bigint but expression is of type character varying

Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 79
Error |
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Hibernate operation: could not execute statement; bad SQL grammar [n/a]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "sub_unit_id" is of type bigint but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Comment: And if you change those Strings to `UnitObj` instances, what happens?

Comment: @Gregg I edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't that you are using a `String` for an assigned id. The problem is because you haven't told `UserUnitObj` that you are using `value` instead of `id`. By default, GORM will always assign the `FK` to the column named `id`. If you do something different, you have to tell it. See the [documentation here](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html) for instructions on how to do that.